# PHP mail: Multiple recipients?

Tags: php, email

I have this code:

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$to = $row['address'];
}
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "example@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

In my table ("email") I have multiple addresses.
(They are not comma sepparated.)
How could I send my message to all of those addresses?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $addresses[] = $row['address'];
}
$to = implode(", ", $addresses);
```

As specified on the [`mail()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), the "to" parameter of the function can take a comma-separated list of addresses.

Comment: @mgraph I'm not sure. Though, it is said in the RFC 2822 that "Each line of characters MUST be no more than 998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters, excluding the CRLF.". http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html

Answer (score 9):

Separate the addresses with commas.

```
$to=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($to, $row['address']);
}

...

mail(implode(',', $to), $submit, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: your line 3 could also be written as $to[] = $row['address']; with a lot less characters. :)

Answer (score 3):

I just tested the codes you presented and before using them, people need to know that using this way (multiple addresses in 'to' field), every single person in that email can see all the destinatars.

Also, if you're using Bcc, they'll also know the first person in the list.

Be aware! :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to return the results separated by `','`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(address) FROM email");
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Alex's answer above, recipients will know the first person in the list even if you're using BCC. A solution for this would be to send individual copies to each address one by one.

```
$emails = ['a@example.com', 'b@example.com', 'c@example.com'];
foreach ($emails as $email){ // or $result as $row
  mail(
    $email, // or $row['address']
    'Same Subject',
    'Same Content',
    'From: same_sender@example.com',
    '-f same_sender@example.com'
  );
}
```