# 1 PHP contact form - 2 Actions - Send info to Email & External API / DB

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a contact form on my site. It can either use PHP script to capture data and email it to me, or send it to API directly, by changing `<form action="">`

By API i mean a script that captures info and saves it to external DB. The API is based on ASP (this is my presumption), and I have no access to it, and have to use the format specified below.

I need to modify the PHP script, so it send info by email AND to the external API using this SPECIFIC format using POST method.

*Disclaimer: I'm not a programmer, but I can figure our how to do things, if pointed in the right direction.*

The format in wich API accepts info:

```
<form action="https://api.somsite.com/?user=&key=&zipcode=&name=&phone=&email=&address=&service=" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="user" value="12345"/>
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="0987654321"/>
```

Hidden values (USER and KEY) are used so API knows where info came from.

Other inputs are provided by user (Name, Email, Zip, Phone, Address, Service).

Here is what my current PHP script looks like:

```
<?php session_start(); ?><?php

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "LEAD";
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$address = $_REQUEST["address"];
$zip = $_REQUEST["zipcode"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["phone"];
$service = $_REQUEST["service"];
$user = $_REQUEST["user"];
$key = $_REQUEST["key"];

$dodgy_strings = array(
                "content-type:"
                ,"mime-version:"
                ,"multipart/mixed"
                ,"bcc:"
);

$msg = 'Name: '.$name. PHP_EOL;
$msg .= 'Phone: '.$phone. PHP_EOL;
$msg .= 'E-mail: '.$email. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
$msg .= 'Address: '.$address. PHP_EOL;
$msg .= 'Zip code: '.$zip. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
$msg .= 'Service: '.$service. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
$msg .= 'User ID: '.$user. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
$msg .= 'Access Key: '.$key. PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
$msg .= PHP_EOL;

mail($to, $subject, $msg);

header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/thankyou.htm'); // This redirects to Thank You page

?>
```

**Basically, I need to use the above PHP script together with some sort of CURL function, or similar.**

I read somewhere on STACK that I would need to us CURL function in PHP, but have no idea how to implement it.

Please help - I would appreciate it VERY VERY much.

Sincerely, Leo.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: @ skrilled - Thanks, i've been to that page. My problem is that I'm not a programmer, and don't understand how to put it all together, so that PHP script would ALSO send the info to the "API" as if it was sent directly from HTML form using: <form action="api.somsite.com/?user=&key=&zipcode=&name=&phone=&email=&address=&service=" method="post">

Any help on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example curl call with a 5 second timeout, posting data. The resulting $data variable is the resulting page of the call.

```
$url='http://www.website.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$postdata = array(
    'post_variable1'=>'post_value1'
    );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

edit: using this example you could pass in POST variables as follows thus replacing where i set $postdata above -

```
$postdata = array('email'=>$_POST['email'], 'phone'=>$_POST['phone']);
```

Comment: How do I make this CURL function relay the data "as if" it was sent by the form: <form action="api.somsite.com/?user=&key=&zipcode=&name=&phone=&email=&address=&servic‌​e=" method="post">

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is to edit your form method to be `method="get"`.

When you use direction url, you lose your information.
You may fix it.

```
<form action="ContactUs.php" method="get">
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: @ eitank - right now I do use '<form action="contact.php" method="post">' and it works (PHP sends info to my email). What I need to do is have the CONTACT.php forward the info to the "API" and send it to me by email.

Comment: form whose method attribute is GET, automatically enters the form packet information through the URL address. Therefore, we don't need to do it manually.

Comment: @ eitank - thank you. My issue is that the API i'm working with is very finicky , and it took me hours to figure out the POST method with a simple html form. Now I need to configure a PHP script to receive the info from <form> and forward it to the external API and email. Using GET will confuse me even more, especially with API documentation being net user friendly at all. Besides, GET does not solve the issue with configuring PHP script. I need help with that.

Comment: @ eitank - i will change POST to GET and see if my PHP script accepts it. Right now it works just fine with POST ... and once again what I need is the PHP help. Thanks!

Comment: php in its current form (code above) works (with POST). There is a submit button. It is a normal contact form. However I need to have same PHP script to ALSO send the info to extern API

Comment: Send a copy to a backup email.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389035/php-mail-multiple-recipients.

Comment: @ - eitank - that's not what I need.