# How do i send mails to multiple recipients

Tags: php

I am trying to simulate an email behavior using a database. These are the codes i used for sending mail to one recipient. How do i send it to multiple recipients.

```
    if($to=="" || $sub=="" || $msg=="")
    {
        $err= "<h3 style='color:red'>fill the related data first</h3>";
    }
    else
    {   
        $d=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userinfo where email='$to'");
        $row=mysqli_num_rows($d);
        if($row==1)
        {
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO usermail values('','$to','$id','$sub','$msg','$file',sysdate())");

            $err= "<h3 style='color:blue'>Message sent...</h3>";
        }
        else
        {
            $sub=$sub."--"."msg failed";
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO usermail values('','$id','$id','$sub','$msg','$file',sysdate())");
            $err= "<h3 style='color:red'>Message failed because reciever not found...</h3>";
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Nothing in this code sends emails.

Comment: @FrankerZ haha. Perhaps some other process periodically checks the `usermail` table...?

Comment: Be clarify with your question and code. add comments in code.

Comment: if you're using [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) then you can comma separate a list of recipients: `johny@example.com, sally@example.com`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail: Multiple recipients?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389035/php-mail-multiple-recipients)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions That was an edit after I made my comment

Answer (score 1):

If i got your problem:

Lets say `$to="abc@x.com;zdf@x.com";`

```
else
{ 
   $toStack = explode(';',$to);
   foreach($toStack as $to){
     $d=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userinfo where email='$to'");
     /** and the rest of your code from the else block **/
   }
}
```

have a nice day..