# Sending email to multiple addresses with php

Tags: php, email

It only sends email to the first email address. The second email address does not work because it is a variable. What do you think?

```
  $to = "email1@gmail.com,". $rs['email2'];
    $subject = "Hello";
    $from = "admin@itservice.com";
    $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
      ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"1a2a3a\"";


    $message .= "This is a message..."
      ."--1a2a3a\r\n";

    $file = file_get_contents("memomemomemo4.pdf");



    // Send email

      $success = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: You [seem to be doing it correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7389058/1790644) by using a comma separated value. My assumption is that the variable is empty. Try debugging the value of $to before submitting the message.

Comment: echo out $to right before $success. And where are you firing success? It's only being assigned, you're not running the function mail anywhere

Comment: $to = $rs['email1'] . ",email2@gmail.com";
It works this way. But it can never send email to the variable email address, It only sends to the string one.

Comment: Does echo $rs['email2']; actually contain anything

Comment: Of course it contains. I echoed it.  It is like mail1@gmail.com, mail2@gmail.com.  Nothing is wrong with it.

Comment: Because you echo it doesn't mean it contains something and isn't an empty string or something lol. Try removing the space after your comma

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this syntax instead:

```
$to = "email1@gmail.com,".$rs['email2'];
```

Comment: Another fun fact, you also could write `"email1@gmail.com,$rs['email2']";`

Comment: A funnier fact, both of these open the application to [header injection](http://securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection).

Comment: This syntax is being echoed like "email1@gmail.comemail2@gmail.com,"  No blank space and no ",". Very strange...

Comment: Another fun FACT unlike your NON FACT `"email1@gmail.com,$rs['email2']";` == `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`

Comment: Another `$to = "email1@gmail.com,".$rs['email2'];` === `$to = "email1@gmail.com,". $rs['email2'];` removing the space does nothing

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
$rs['email2'] = "me@me.com";
echo "email1@gmail.com,{$rs['email2']}";
# email1@gmail.com,me@me.com
```

Comment: I dont know why but it does not see variables.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?