# PHP send email to multiple email addresses obtained from input field

Tags: php, email, post

I want to send an invitation to multiple email addresses using my form.

I want users to enter multiple email addresses in the form (up to 4) and then an invitation to join my website will be sent to those email addresses.

But I can't find a solution to send emails to multiple recipients using a PHP form.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php 
    if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
        $email_to = $_POST['email'];
        $email_to = $_POST['email1'];
        $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
        $mailheader = "From: Marsh Children Home 
        <hola@marshchildrenshome.org.mx>\r\n"; 
        $mailheader .= "Reply-To: hola@marshchildrenshome.org.mx\r\n"; 
        $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]).""; 
        mail($email_to, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die 
        ("Failure"); 
?>
```

But it's sending email to only one recipient `email1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail: Multiple recipients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389035/php-mail-multiple-recipients)

Comment: Sorry, but I am not fetching data from db in my case.

Comment: are you doing this with an array of addresses?

Comment: Since you have only two addresses, just create a new variable and add as an extra recipient

Comment: @Marinapriyanka The principle is the same: create a comma-separated string of the email-addresses: `$email_to = $_POST['email'] . ', ' . $_POST['email1'] . ', ' . $_POST['email2'] // etc.`.

Comment: That concatenation example will break functionality if some of the vars aren't set, you'll end up with 'blah@blah.com,,,'

Comment: @DecentDabbler thanks, it worked for me.

Comment: @delboy1978uk That's a good point, yes. OP will have to rigorously validate input, making sure they're valid addresses first, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First explode your Emails string, by using **explode** into comma separated array and then use for each loop to send the emails. for example you can do this

```
$toEmails=explode(";" , $_POST['email']); //you have array now

 //loop through the array to send email to each user  
 foreach($toEmails as $toEmail)
    {
    mail($toEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
     }
```

Comment: He has 4 fields, not one.

Comment: @delboy1978uk it is just a example to show OP how to solve her problem.

Answer (score -2):

You are instantly overwriting `$email_to` in the following line!
Try this:

```
$email_to .= ';'.$_POST['email1'];
```

Also, I should point out that you should be filtering and validating yopur $_POST data before using it!

The other option is 4 vars for the 4 possible emails:

```
$email2 = $_POST['email2']; //etc
```

Then check it isn't empty:

```
if (!empty($email2)) {
    mail($email2, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("Failure");
}
```

Comment: I really don't know how to do it. I just tried this option but it didn't work.

Comment: I am overwriting it because I want to send the form data to multiple recipients but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: A bit quick to vote me down, I edited my answer with some more detail.

Comment: Your other option is four vars for the 4 emails, and call mail() up to four times, if the other vars aren't empty.

Comment: will filtering and validating $_POST data will solve my issue?

Comment: No, it's more of a security precaution. Are these emails to go separately or together with more than one recipient?

Comment: I tried adding 4 vars for 4 emails but didn't help, can you edit your answer with an example code. Thanks