# Multiple recipients with mail() in $to or $additinional_headers?

Tags: php, email

When I use [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.mail.php) I can specify the recipients in the parameter `$to` or in the `$additional_headers`. I think `$to` cannot be empty, so there must be at least one recipient. Is that correct? If further recipients should be added, does it make a difference if it is appended to `$to` or if is set with `"To: "` entries in `$additional_headers`?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389035/php-mail-multiple-recipients for mailing multiple recipients.

Comment: @uday8486 I was asking if it is a difference, not how to do it.

Comment: why don't you test it and see what the final email looks like, in each case? Then you'll know if there's any difference.

Comment: @ADyson Not sure how to do that the right way. Besides, the outcome would may only be my impression and cannot be used for all situations.

Comment: "Not sure how to do that the right way"...what do you mean? In the question you've described the difference between the two scenarios - addresses appended to $to, and addresses appended via "To" entries in the additional headers. So just write code to send emails to the same set of addresses, but using each of those different approaches. It's unclear what specifically you don't know how to do?

Comment: True, the outcome would be your impression, but it's a test result. If you repeat the tests and get consistent results, that's likely to be the expected behaviour. I suppose you could also go and read the [source code of the mail function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/mail.c) and see if you can work out what it will do in each scenario,

Comment: @ADyson Yes, the source code contains probably the definit answer. Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with C.

Comment: Me neither. Which is why testing it is probably the simplest thing to do. if you create the correct test conditions you can reliably observe the behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use below code to send an email for multiple recipients:

```
$email_to = "abct@another.com,some@other.com,yet@another.net";
```

If you need to add emails as CC or BCC, add the following part in the variable you use as for your header :

```
$headers .= "CC: sombodyelse@noplace.com".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "BCC: hidden@special.com".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: OP knows that. That isn't the question. Read it again.